# How do I use CloudFront as my asset CDN with Heroku review apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-cloudfront

Heroku [strongly discourages](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/please-do-not-use-asset-sync) using AssetSync to populate an S3 bucket, which can then be used as the CF distribution origin. Instead, they suggest using [your Heroku app](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn#creating-a-distribution) as the origin.

How can this be made to work with [review apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration-review-apps), which are ephemeral and have variable hostnames? It's not reasonable to configure a new CloudFront distribution or origin for every review build; this defeats the seamless and disposable nature of review apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, you should not use a CDN for review apps. Instead: just access the review apps directly via the browser, and see how things work.

The whole purpose of things like AssetSync or a CDN is to pre-cache images and other static assets for speed. For review apps where you're simply testing something in a one-off manner to verify behavior: this is just a pointless optimization.

My advice: use a CDN in production, and use Heroku directly for all other environments. The small performance improvement isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up not using the CDN for review apps. Assuming your CDN host is stored as a config variable on your staging app, you need to adjust your app.json to make sure that variable is not copied over for the review apps.

That way you can use CDNs for staging and production environments but access assets directly via heroku for review apps. If you push the review app to staging, it should use the CDN config var from the staging app. You can do any CDN-related testing in staging before deploying to production.

Comment: Yup, this is precisely the advice above from @rdegges.